# Is there a way to pay multiple lightning addresses from a single invoice

Tags: lightning-network, invoices

Let's say I'm an online platform that wants to enable lightning payments between members, but want to also take a small sats fee per transaction to cover platform costs. Very much like Uber or AirBnB etc run.

Is there a way to facilitate this with lightning so I avoid becoming an intermediary proxying funds and instead a single invoice translates to 2 (or more) peer-to-peer  payments?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to facilitate this with lightning so I avoid becoming an intermediary proxying funds and instead a single invoice translates to 2 (or more) peer-to-peer payments?

yes and no, yes with bolt12, no without but you can use the keysend to send a payment

This is how I am implementing tipping a plugin developer in core lightning ([See](https://github.com/coffee-tools/coffee/issues/137))

The basic idea is that you get the payment of X and then in your lightning node you intercept this event and pay the node that you want to may with a fraction of this payment with keysend.

With keysend you can pay a node with a public key and not with an invoice, ofcs if all the node implements bolt12 you can use a bolt12 invoice with any amount instead of a keysend

Do this in core lightning is trivial I do not know with others implementations